# Edit Names of FDF Fields in Pdf

Tags: pdf, fdf

are there any programmatic methods to change the field names of the FDF data within a pdf. Ok even if it creates another pdf with different FDF field names.

For instance:

```
pdftk example.pdf generate_fdf output out.fdf
```

I want to edit the values of `out.fdf` and change them in the original pdf.

Comment: There is no specific fdf data in pdfs, form architecture is defined in pdf terms.

Comment: FDF is the form data interchange format specific to Acrobat. Some other PDF application vendors have adopted it. XFDF is the XML based ISO equivalent. If you want different field names to be used in the FDF, you need to rename the fields in the PDF since that is what the names are based on.